# How can I query a database created using the previous core version from the new core version?

Tags: 8, database, drush

I want to query users, nodes etc in my D7 database that I am currently migrating to D8 to compare with the migrated content.

I want to use custom Drush commands to run some checks.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, not really. You can query data from as secondary database, Drupal or otherwise, but you won't be able to load D8 objects from a D7 database - the underlying architecture is incompatible.

Comment: Ah ok I thought that might be the case. Thanks. Great talk @DrupalSouth too btw ;)

Comment: Thanks!  (post must be 15 characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add external databases in your settings.php file:

```
$databases['external']['default']= array(
  'database'=>'',
  'username'=>'',
  'password'=>'',
  'prefix'=>'',
  'host'=>'',
  'port'=>'3306',
  'namespace'=>'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver'=>'mysql',
);
```

Then, in a custom module you can query for nodes, terms etc.

```
// Switch to external database
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('external');

// Get a connection going
$db = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();

$vid = 5; // The vocabulary I want to query
$query = $db->select('taxonomy_term_data', 't');
$query
  ->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'h', 'h.tid = t.tid');
$query
  ->addTag('translatable')
  ->addTag('taxonomy_term_access')
  ->fields('t')
  ->fields('h', array(
    'parent',
  ))
  ->condition('t.vid', $vid)
  ->orderBy('t.weight')
  ->orderBy('t.name');
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Switch back to your current db

```
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
```

Save the results to a d8 vocabulary

```
foreach($results as $result) {
  Term::create([
    'tid' => $result->tid,
    'name' => $result->name,
    'vid' => 'my_d8_vocabulary_name'
   ])->enforceIsNew()->save();
}
```